# In what format the day need to be specified in date?

Tags: date

Is it

```
\date{April 5, 2022}
```

or

```
\date{April 05, 2022}
```

Is that leading `0` necessary for days?

Comment: Not a Latex question but the leading zero is not necessary.

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 for more information.

Comment: Is there any wrong if the zero is added?

Comment: I am not an expert on this topic but I like the leading zero in my personal documents.

Comment: I can't see why this was closed as off topic, is asking for the synax of `\date`

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner ^

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I understood the question very differently than you apparently :). My understanding was, that the OP asked if it ok from a "best practice" point of view to write "05" vs. "5" (independent of LaTeX). I might be wrong of course (and it looks like I was wrong seeing the OP accepted your answer and did not comment further).

Comment: @ZoltanKing Is your question about LaTeX (about the `\date` command) or are you asking about the format of dates in general?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I pinged you after my answer was accepted so I assumed it was the right interpretation:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle :). I was ar work in meetings etc and did not check the website very often. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not provided any example but in the standard classes such as `article` LaTeX does no processing of the date it is just a string that is typeset under the title so there is no format restriction:

```
   \date{I think it's today, but it could be yesterday}
```

is fine.